# Can I create multiple API endpoints with the same HTTP method and non-variable URIs?

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, routes, asp.net-web-api2

I have two API endpoints defined as such:

```
[Route("create")]
[HttpPost]
[ResponseType(typeof(User))]
public async Task<IHttpActionResult> CreateUser(User user)

[Route("login")]
[HttpPost]
[ResponseType(typeof (User))]
public async Task<IHttpActionResult> Login(string email, string password)
```

And the controller defined as

```
[RoutePrefix("api/users")]
public class UserController : ApiController
```

When I call it with this information (both in plain chrome, my app and the Postman application)

```
POST /api/users/login HTTP/1.1
Host: mysite.azurewebsites.net
Cache-Control: no-cache
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded

email=somemail&password=somepw
```

I receive a 404:

```
{
    "Message": "No HTTP resource was found that matches the request URI 'http://mysite.azurewebsites.net/api/users/login'.",
    "MessageDetail": "No action was found on the controller 'User' that matches the request."
}
```

It does work for another route which I can call with `/api/users/1`:

```
[Route("{id:int}")]
[HttpGet]
[ResponseType(typeof(User))]
public async Task<IHttpActionResult> GetUser(int? id)
```

Can't I explicitly define such endpoints? I tried creating a custom route but this made no difference (I placed this before the default route and after calling `config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes()`).

```
config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
      name: "Login",
      routeTemplate: "api/users/login",
      defaults: new { controller = "User", action = "Login" }
);
```

Note that explicitly defining the route as `[Route("~api/users/login")]` didn't work either.

I have also noticed that routes in my other controller don't seem to work anymore. More specifically I have these definitions:

```
[RoutePrefix("api/movies")]
public class MovieController : BaseController

[Route("~api/genres")]
[HttpGet]
[ResponseType(typeof(IEnumerable<Genre>))]
public IHttpActionResult GetGenres()

[Route("~api/genres/{id:int}")]
[HttpGet]
[ResponseType(typeof(IEnumerable<MovieResult>))]
public IHttpActionResult GetMoviesForGenre(int id)

[Route("{id:int}")]
[HttpGet]
[ResponseType(typeof(Movie))]
public IHttpActionResult GetMovieDetails(int id)
```

Of these options, only a call to `/api/movies/16` succeeds, the others return

> No type was found that matches the controller named 'genres'.

Is there something elementary I'm overlooking?

I have made the genre routes available again by changing them to `genres` and `genres/{id:int}` and adding this route

```
config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
       name: "test",
       routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{action}/{id}",
       defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
);
```

but I would assume that this shouldn't be necessary. For some reason the request to `/api/movies/genres` works while `/api/users/login` doesn't. I did notice that creating a GET method with URI `/api/users/genres` **DOES** work so I believe it must have something to do with that. Why won't it find my POST-methods?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like there are lots of moving pieces here so it's hard to figure out exactly what will fix all the problems. But here are a couple of issues to address...

Web API (unlike MVC) can only have one parameter read from the request body. So to make your `Login` action work, try to create a `LoginInfo` class...

```
public class LoginInfo
{
    public string email { get; set; }
    public string password { get; set; }
}
```

And change the Login method to...

```
public async Task<IHttpActionResult> Login([FromBody]LoginInfo loginInfo)
```

The issues with the genres appear to be the incorrect usage of `~` in the attribute routing (should be `~/`). Try...

```
[Route("~/api/genres")]
```

and

```
[Route("~/api/genres/{id:int}")]
```

Comment: I appreciate the reply! I actually solved it myself earlier and just about finished writing my answer when I had to leave my desk for a while. Indeed, the `[FromBody]` annotation with a single parameter was the solution (see [here](http://weblog.west-wind.com/posts/2012/Sep/11/Passing-multiple-simple-POST-Values-to-ASPNET-Web-API)) so I'll just accept your answer instead. I'll also take a look into that tilde; I temporarily fixed that by simply using a standard route.